# How to open 3 excel files in the same time using xlwings Python?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I am trying to open all  the .xlsx files from a certain folder. I used xlwings module.
For sure the last line code is not correct. Could you give me a hint?

```
import os
import glob
import xlwings as xw
excels = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\Users\ego\PycharmProjects\TRIAL01\excel files'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
            excels.append(file)
for i in excels:
    xw.Book(r'C:\Users\ego\PycharmProjects\TRIAL01\excel files', i)
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the open files?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint: use the os.path.join() method because your current string will show up as 'C:\Users\ego\PycharmProjects\TRIAL01\excel filesdoc.xlsx' and is missing the connecting backslash.

```
dir = r'C:\Users\ego\PycharmProjects\TRIAL01\excel files'
for i in excels:
    xw.Book(os.path.join(dir, i))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).